# Microsoft Partner Center Issues

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store, microsoft-partner-center

I have been trying to effect payment on Microsoft Partner Center for more than a month without success. The aim is to be able to publish an app that has been on Google Play for months.

The commonest error message I get is this:

```
Something went wrong. Please try again, if the problem persists please contact Microsoft support.
Reference ID: 0760e6e3-<abcd>-<prst>-<uvwx>-08dc379f85f3
```

I have tried this in many ways, including changing browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge), changing PC, clearing browser cache, changing credit card (several of them) and none of those helped. The Microsoft support the message is referring to can't be reached because the very first step of payment has to be completed.

Looking into forums within Microsoft shows this to be a persistent problem with many of the responses from Microsoft being of no help at all, referring people from one forum to the other.

Any help on this?

Comment: Please open a free support ticket here: **[Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support)**. Go to **Contact us** tab, find **Non-Technical Support - Dashboard** and choose **SUBMIT AN INCIDENT**. You could talk to the store team directly and confirm this behavior.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I have just tried that, it sends me to Services Hub then to Partner Center. On the partner center it is automated, from which it referred me back to my account help and support section, the same place I could not select workspace. It then asks me to review solutions. The solution is the same response I got from Partner Center automated solutions. None of which worked. Why is this such a big issue with Microsoft? How come it is so smooth with Google Play Console? Is there a hidden agenda?

Comment: Make sure to sign in with email associated with Partner Center account, please do not modify the default category https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qdec.png

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I have done it again based on your instructions. I'm hoping someone will resolve it. Thank you for your concern and help.